# ClassFormatError: Field "_callee__a1" in class <Unknown> has illegal signature "_callee"

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

Some exception occurs when I try to inline two classes:

```
public class CI_Caller1 {
    private int _data;
    private CI_Callee_2 _callee;

    public CI_Caller1(int data, CI_Callee_2 callee){
        _data = data;
        _callee = callee;
    }
}

public class CI_Callee_2 {

    private Integer _a1;
    private String _t;

    public CI_Callee_2(Integer a1, String t){
        _a1 = a1;
        _t = t;
    }
}
```

The inling operation is to inline two fields, _a and _t in CI_Callee_2, as a member of CI_Caller1. The new member would be:

```
private int _data;
private Integer _callee__a1;
private String _callee__t;
```

Everything seems correct, but when i try to load the generated byte[], exception is thrown as:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Field "_callee__a1" in class <Unknown> has illegal signature "_callee"
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
    at code.jit.asm.services.ACLoader.loadClass(ACLoader.java:27)
```

The way to vistiField is like:

```
    _fieldNode = reference2CI_Callee_2FieldNode();
    //cw is class visitor to the CI_Caller1
    cw.visitField(_fieldNode.access, calculateName(fieldHoster, _fieldNode.name), 
            _fieldNode.desc, _fieldNode.signature, _fieldNode.value);
```

The `_fieldNode` here references to a `CI_Callee_2`'s field, and its original members (and its values):

```
desc: Ljava/lang/Integer;
name: _a1     //calculateName will map _a1 to _callee_a1
signature: null
value: null
```

I did not make any change on the _fieldNode once it is initilized with ClassNode of CI_Callee_2. (The `signature` value of _fieldNode keeps NULL all the time)

Is there anyone seen this exception? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The field you created with the name "_callee__a1" has the signature `_callee`. The character `_` is not a valid start of a field signature. You say you want the type to be `Integer`, so the field signature should be `Ljava/lang/Integer;`. (The `L` indicates that this is a reference type)

Comment: Still confused. 1)  I can not understand why there is signature ``_callee`` in the generated code, because ``_fieldNode.signature`` for visitField is NULL and it is initialized with classNode of CI_Callee2(never change).  2) What's the difference between ``signature`` and ``desc``? The "Ljava/lang/Integer;"  is description and it has already been passed to cw.visitField as ``desc`` correctly.

Comment: I have fixed it. The problem is in another place  where I passed wrong string '_callee' as desc for putField instruction.

Comment: @shijie xu: the ASM API uses names which are a bit misleading. `desc` is what is called *signature* elsewhere while `signature` is the *generic signature* which may be `null`.

Comment: ASM uses the terms "descriptor" (shortened "desc") and "signature" in the same way as the JVM specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3